# R - How to copy the contents of one collection into another using Mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

We are using MongoDB to store a number of identically structured databases that need to be combined into one database, and am using Mongolite to manipulate the database rather than just query it.

We generate 365 databases with a single one being made every single day, each with the same collections: Cars, Customers, Personnel. Within each of those collections, they have identical fields (such as customerID, carModel, or employeeID) for each of the 365 databases. My objective is to copy all of the data from those 365 databases into one database so that all of it can be queried at the same time. I'm not trying to combine any of the different collections together, but rather copy the contents of all of the Customers collections into a single Customers collection.

I found the following command on the MongoDB user's guide:

db.collection.copyTo()

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/

Based on the documentation, it seems that this would achieve my goal, but I'm not sure how to do this using Mongolite and the run() command. If that is not possible, my next question would is whether I can embed command line scripting / bash scripting inside my R code in order to execute MongoDB commands from within a R script.

Thanks in advance for any assistance in using MongoLite, I am still quite the novice!

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the same question and couldn't find a direct answer, however, there's an indirect way to copy the content of a collection to another. The readme page mentions of [mongolite](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite) mentions that you can first stream jsonlines into a connection (which would a tmp file), then import into your other collection:

```
# Stream jsonlines into a connection
tmp <- tempfile()
m$export(file(tmp))
# Stream it back in R
library(jsonlite)
m2$import(file(tmp))
```

I copied this code from readme page of [mongolite](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite). I personally tried this solution and it works.